# Minikube error states a bound pvc is not found

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

When the resource file is applied the pod reports a persistentvolumeclaim "pm-pv-claim" not found. However, the pvc is present and bound. Why does the pod say it cannot find the pvc?

Many forum posts suggest the issue relates to how Minikube handles storage, but solutions suggested there to explicitly declare the PV did not work for me. Other posts have the pvc and pv in unbound states, which does not apply here.

Details:

```yaml
cmdline ~> kubectl describe pod pimgr-5df8f859d-z8xmz
Name:         pimgr-5df8f859d-z8xmz
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         m01/192.168.99.10
Start Time:   Sun, 30 Aug 2020 22:00:24 +0100
Labels:       app=pimgr
              pod-template-hash=5df8f8569d
              tier=frontend
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Running
IP:           172.17.0.6
IPs:
  IP:           172.17.0.6
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/pimgr-5df8f8569d
Containers:
  pimgr:
    Container ID:   docker://5ca322e180283135d5b160a54ab0a46404381951d2b1ffa6c034df7c85f638
    Image:          pimgr/django:0.1
    Image ID:       docker://sha256:23abfa4de71126724c1fff6bda67ff8c093f903086718541be61f0be4097b3
    Port:           8010/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Sun, 30 Aug 2020 22:01:08 +0100
      Finished:     Sun, 30 Aug 2020 22:01:08 +0100
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Sun, 30 Aug 2020 22:00:38 +0100
      Finished:     Sun, 30 Aug 2020 22:00:38 +0100
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  3
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /code from pimgr-persistent-storage (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-llll4 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  pimgr-persistent-storage:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  pm-pv-claim
    ReadOnly:   false
  default-token-llll4:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-llll4
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age               From               Message
  ----     ------            ----              ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  <unknown>         default-scheduler  persistentvolumeclaim "pm-pv-claim" not found
  Warning  FailedScheduling  <unknown>         default-scheduler  error while running "VolumeBinding" filter plugin for pod "pimgr-5df8f8569d-z8xmz": pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims
  Warning  FailedScheduling  <unknown>         default-scheduler  error while running "VolumeBinding" filter plugin for pod "pimgr-5df8f8569d-z8xmz": pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims
  Normal   Scheduled         <unknown>         default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/pimgr-5df8f8569d-z8xmz to m01
  Normal   Pulled            1s (x4 over 45s)  kubelet, m01       Container image "pimgr/django:0.1" already present on machine
  Normal   Created           1s (x4 over 45s)  kubelet, m01       Created container pimgr
  Normal   Started           1s (x4 over 45s)  kubelet, m01       Started container pimgr
  Warning  BackOff           0s (x5 over 43s)  kubelet, m01       Back-off restarting failed container
```

**resource.yaml**

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: pimgr
  labels:
    app: pimgr
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 8010
  selector:
    app: pimgr
    tier: frontend
  type: LoadBalancer
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: pm-pv-claim
  labels:
    app: pimgr
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 4Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv0001
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  hostPath:
    path: /data/pv0001/
  storageClassName: standard
---
apiVersion: apps/v1 # for versions before 1.9.0 use apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: pimgr
  labels:
    app: pimgr
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: pimgr
      tier: frontend
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: pimgr
        tier: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: pimgr/django:0.1
        name: pimgr
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8010
          name: pimgr
        volumeMounts:
        - name: pimgr-persistent-storage
          mountPath: /code
      volumes:
      - name: pimgr-persistent-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: pm-pv-claim
```

```
cmdline ~> kubectl get pods
NAME                          READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
pimgr-5df8f8569d-z8xmz        0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   2          36s
```

```sh
cmdline> kubectl get pvc
NAME                STATUS   VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
pm-pv-claim         Bound    pv0001                                     5Gi        RWO            standard       20m
```

```sh
cmdline> minikube version
minikube version: v1.8.2
commit: eb13446e786c9ef70cb0a9f85a633194e62396a1
```

```sh
cmdline ~> kubectl get pv
NAME                                       CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM                       STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE
pv0001                                     5Gi        RWO            Retain           Bound    default/pm-pv-claim         standard                13h
```

```sh
cmdline > minikube addons list
|-----------------------------|----------|--------------|
|         ADDON NAME          | PROFILE  |    STATUS    |
|-----------------------------|----------|--------------|
| dashboard                   | minikube | disabled     |
| default-storageclass        | minikube | enabled ✅   |
| efk                         | minikube | disabled     |
| freshpod                    | minikube | disabled     |
| gvisor                      | minikube | disabled     |
| helm-tiller                 | minikube | disabled     |
| ingress                     | minikube | disabled     |
| ingress-dns                 | minikube | disabled     |
| istio                       | minikube | disabled     |
| istio-provisioner           | minikube | disabled     |
| logviewer                   | minikube | disabled     |
| metrics-server              | minikube | disabled     |
| nvidia-driver-installer     | minikube | disabled     |
| nvidia-gpu-device-plugin    | minikube | disabled     |
| registry                    | minikube | disabled     |
| registry-creds              | minikube | disabled     |
| storage-provisioner         | minikube | enabled ✅   |
| storage-provisioner-gluster | minikube | disabled     |
|-----------------------------|----------|--------------|
```

```sh
cmdline > kubectl get storageclass
NAME                 PROVISIONER                RECLAIMPOLICY   VOLUMEBINDINGMODE   ALLOWVOLUMEEXPANSION   AGE
standard (default)   k8s.io/minikube-hostpath   Delete          Immediate           false                  91d
```

**Update:**

Its seems that the binding did succeed: I modified the spec/containers to:

```sh
      containers:
      - image: pimgr/django:0.1
        name: pimgr
        command: ["ls"]
        args: ["-l", "/code1"]
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8010
          name: pimgr
        volumeMounts:
        - name: pimgr-persistent-storage
          mountPath: /code1
```

and then added a file in the minikube vm by:

```sh
$ sudo touch /data/pv0001/hi
$ ls /data/pv0001/
hi
```

after applying the resource I saw:

```sh
cmdline ~> kubectl get pods
NAME                          READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
pimgr-55696d6dc4-gz74c        0/1     Completed          0          4s
cmdline ~> kubectl logs pimgr-55696d6dc4-gz74c
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Aug 31 15:06 hi
```

However the not found error is still present:

```sh
cmdline ~> kubectl describe pod pimgr-55696d6dc4-gz74c
Name:         pimgr-55696d6dc4-gz74c
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         m01/192.168.99.103
Start Time:   Mon, 31 Aug 2020 16:11:38 +0100
Labels:       app=pimgr
              pod-template-hash=55696d6dc4
              tier=frontend
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Running
IP:           172.17.0.6
IPs:
  IP:           172.17.0.6
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/pimgr-55696d6dc4
Containers:
  pimgr:
    Container ID:  docker://4f4ceb807eb4d97e69a6af2da853561ca6c82006de545c68b7d2013da2aacc21
    Image:         pimgr/django:0.1
    Image ID:      docker://sha256:23abfa4de71126724c1fff6bda67ff8c093f903086718541be61f0be4097b3ee
    Port:          8010/TCP
    Host Port:     0/TCP
    Command:
      ls
    Args:
      -l
      /code1
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Mon, 31 Aug 2020 16:11:52 +0100
      Finished:     Mon, 31 Aug 2020 16:11:52 +0100
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  2
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /code1 from pimgr-persistent-storage (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-llll4 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  pimgr-persistent-storage:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  pm-pv-claim
    ReadOnly:   false
  default-token-llll4:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-llll4
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                From               Message
  ----     ------            ----               ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  34s (x2 over 34s)  default-scheduler  persistentvolumeclaim "pm-pv-claim" not found
  Normal   Scheduled         32s                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/pimgr-55696d6dc4-gz74c to m01
  Normal   Pulled            18s (x3 over 31s)  kubelet, m01       Container image "pimgr/django:0.1" already present on machine
  Normal   Created           18s (x3 over 31s)  kubelet, m01       Created container pimgr
  Normal   Started           18s (x3 over 31s)  kubelet, m01       Started container pimgr
  Warning  BackOff           6s (x4 over 29s)   kubelet, m01       Back-off restarting failed container
```

So it appears to have correctly bound, but my original question still stands, why is it reporting that it was not found? Is this a red-herring or an issue elsewhere?

Comment: looks like this is not a PVC related issue if it was a pvc related issue the pods should be in pending state but it is in crashbacklookoff state. there might be a issue related with the application.

Comment: Could you please show us the output of `minikube addons list` and also tell us which version of Minikube are you using?

Comment: @Mr.Fix I partly agree - see my update above - when I bypass the application I can see the successful mapping of a file from the host into my pod, so the pvc binding has succeeded. It doesn't seem clear to me why the error message arises.

Comment: It may make sense to edit the first paragraph above to de-emphasise the 'CrashLoopBackOff' as that seems to arise later in the pod startup sequqnce

Comment: @OhHiMark  I have added the addons - the version (1.8.2) was already there a bit further up - I've made it a bit clearer

Comment: @Mazerunner72 Could you also show us your StorageClass yaml?

Comment: @OhHiMark, I've added storageclass just above the update section.

Comment: @Mazerunner72 1. Are you able to exclude any versions mismatch? 2. Are your selectors properly set? 3. Are you able to reproduce this issue after the update you made?